# htaccess file modifications - CakePHP

Tags: file, .htaccess, cakephp, upload

I need to increase the maximum file upload size in cakephp.
I have looked around and seen that using ini_set in the controller or pretty much anywhere in the code is useless.
So my next option is to modify the htaccess file.

I looked around and found some changes to make such as the,
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_execution_time
max_input_time

My question is, which .htaccess file do I need to change?
And, do the changes go inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags?

There is a .htaccess file the root folder, the app folder and the webroot folder.

Thanks

Comment: are you working on localhost or this concern is for live setup?
If live setup then there will be setting in cPanel and for localhost you can modify php.ini for the installation.

Comment: @LokenMakwana - Its for localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the changes in the .htaccess file in the webroot folder as it is the only .htaccess file used if you have a [production installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production).

And no, the changes do not have to be inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, this is only necessary for mod_rewrite related config settings.